# Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException Missing required parameters for [Route: products] [URI: products/delete/{id}]

Tags: laravel, required

This is My route in the file of `Web.php`

What I am doing wrong?

```
 Route::get('/products/delete/{id}',[ProductsController::class, 'delete'])->name('products');
```

This is my product blade file

```
 <a href="products/delete/{{$product->id}}">Delete</a>
```

Here is My Product Controller Function

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $product=Product::find($id);
    $product->delete();
    return redirect()->route('products');
}
```

Comment: `redirect()->route('products')` this route has a required parameter, `id` ... you probably want to redirect to a different route ... your delete route should probably have a different name so you can have `products` be the index route

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
return redirect()->back()
```

Or redirect to any other route instead to redirect to same route

Answer (score 0):

```
//Its working Correctly after changes in my Routs and paths and functions 
//I change in my blade file

<a href="products/delete/{{$product->id}}">Delete</a>

//This is My route in the file of Web.php (i made change in my Route::get)


Route::get('products/delete/{id}',[ProductsController::class, 'delete']);

//Here is My Product Controller Function (Made Litte changes)

public function delete($id)
    {
        $product=Product::findorfail($id);
        if($product){
            $product->delete();
            return back()->with('deleted', "Record Deleted Successfully");
        }else{
            return back()->with('Error', "Record Not Found");
        }

    }
```